# How to add a pandas Series to a DataFrame ignoring indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with random, unsorted row indices, which is a result of removing some 'noise' from the original DataFrame.

```
row_index    col1 col2
        2    1    2
       19    3    4
      432    4    1
```

I would like to add some pd.Series to this Dataframe. The Series has its indices sorted from 0 to n=number of rows. The number of rows equals the number of rows in the DataFrame

Having tried multiple ways of adding the Series to my DataFrame I realized that the data from the Series gets mixed up, because (I believe) Python is matching records by their indices.

Is there a way I can add the Series to the Dataframe, ignoring the indices, so that my data doesn't get mixed up?

Comment: `series.index=df.index` and then you can add it, or `ignore_index=True`, when concat

Comment: @anky_91 This is exactly what I needed, thanks for that!

Comment: No problem.. :) Cheers..!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

convert the series into a data frame.

```
# code

df = pd.DataFrame(df)
result = pd.concat([df1,df], axis=1, ignore_index=True)
```

df1 is the data frame you want to add.

df is the data frame i.e series you converted to data frame

Comment: Nice one! I would imagine `axis=0` is also a common use case.

Comment: Yes, @YonatanN. It is also used widely.

Answer (score 14):

```
df['new_col'] = other_df['column'].values
```